# How To add blank part in video for 1 hour

Tags: after-effects

I have a video of 2 mins length.Now I want to add extra 1 hour to the video.I have done this be changing video duration in composition settings.But video is rendering for about 4 gb.Whereas original video is only 5 mb.

How to render this video in mp4 format with around 10mb size.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the AE encoder can signal duplicate frames (which would keep the size down). You may be better off using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a command-line tool.

Suppose your source video is 1280x720 at 24 fps, then you would run

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=1280x720:r=24:d=3600" -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] -c:v libx264 output.mp4
```

---

To combine with text overlay,

```
ffmpeg -i universal.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=1280x720:r=24000/1001:d=20" -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v];[v]drawtext=fontfile=FreeSerifB‌​old.ttf:text=\'Hello World\':fontcolor=white@1.0:fontsize=16:x=w-tw-10:y=10:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5[vout]" -map [vout] -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -movflags +faststart output.mp4 2>&1
```

Comment: What's the resolution and fps of short video?

Comment: 1280x720 and 24fps

Comment: And also your source video is not 24 fps. It's 23.98 fps, which is 23.976 or precisely 24000/1001 fps.

Comment: Webplayer in the sense HTML5 video player in websites. I am so sorry .  it freezes for 5 to 10 seconds, when you seek in middle .I donno how to describe.It is like video is 1 hour, when i seek to 20th minute,it freeze for 5 to 10 seconds , then contines to play...

Comment: Yes, because, in high profile, which is what libx264 produces by default, many reference frames are used including future frames. So, the player has to decode many frames before it can finally decode the seek point frame. Use edited command.

Comment: Thank you , Please check http://photoapp.biz/api/ffmpeg/universal-full.mp4 , video is not playing for first 30 seconds in chrome

Comment: Also check the output for that video - https://jsfiddle.net/g8m4jsn0/

Comment: Plays here in Chrome 48 correctly with no delay.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36814/discussion-on-answer-by-mulvya-how-to-add-blank-part-in-video-for-1-hour).